# Specify content type for WPF user control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I have a user control which represent a certain data type.
Usually when not using a user control to display data, I can enter the property names of the binding object type, but the user control doesn't know its type.

How can I specify the type for this user control?

Comment: This is what DataTemplates are for.

Comment: Will is correct, you should be using DataTemplates for this, not trying to hardcode it in the UserControl. If you really want to ensure a UserControl is only ever used with a specific object type though, try adding a custom DependencyProperty to your UserControl, and set it up so the DataContext binds to that custom DP.

Comment: I ended up adding d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=model:Event, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"